# Generate a new dictionary from the maximum values in a dictionary with ties

Tags: python, dictionary, max

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
stats = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':2}
```

I need to generate a dictionary that has the maximum values...there can be ties:

```
max_only = {'b':2,'c':2}
```

What is the most pythonic and fastest way to generate the new dictionary where the values are the maximum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to determine the max value:

```
max_value = max(stats.itervalues())
```

then construct your `max_only` dictionary:

```
max_only = {k: v for k, v in stats.iteritems() if v == max_value}
```

For Python 3, substitute `itervalues()` and `iteritems()` with `values()` and `items()` respectively.

It is easier to find *one* key-value pair that is the maximum:

```
dict(max(stats.iteritems(), key=lambda kv: kv[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Almost the above answer:
new_stats = {}
for key,values in stats.items():
  if values == max(stats.values()):
    new_stats[key] = values
```

Comment: This calculates the max value every single loop iteration.